# Add second child of li element in existing ul

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add second and third `li` element in my existing `ul`. But not properly done.

```js
$("ul li:nth-child(2)").append($("<li>").text("ADDDED TEST 5"));
$("ul li:nth-child(3)").append($("<li>").text("ADDDED TEST 6"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="a_rgt">
  <ul>
    <li>TEST1</li>
    <li>TEST2</li>
    <li>TEST3</li>
    <li>TEST4</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: You can't append an `li` element to `li`. `.append($("<li>").text("ADDDED TEST 5"))` will give you `<li><li>...</li></li>`.

Comment: that's the problem, any solution ?

Comment: The one you are trying is actually appending another li's with the ul. what exactly you want ?

Comment: i want to create li element dynamically in this ul element

Comment: you want the 2nd and 3rd one to be replaced with newly created li's ?

Comment: no! i want new li after TEST2 , and another li after TEST3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to add li items after 4:

```
    $("#your_ul_id").append('<li>ADDDED TEST 5</li>');
    $("#your_ul_id").append('<li>ADDDED TEST 6</li>');
```

If you wish to add li items between 2 & 3 use this:

```
$("ul li:nth-child(2)").after($("<li>").text("ADDDED TEST 2.1"));
$("ul li:nth-child(3)").after($("<li>").text("ADDDED TEST 2.2"));
```

OR

```
$("ul li:nth-child(2)").after('<li>ADDDED TEST 2.1</li><li>ADDDED TEST 2.2</li>');
```

Comment: nah! I wish to li element under existing ul

Comment: Your question is not clear. This is the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  $("ul li:nth-child(4)").append("<li>ADDDED TEST " + (i + 5) + "</li>");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="a_rgt">
  <ul>
    <li>TEST1</li>
    <li>TEST2</li>
    <li>TEST3</li>
    <li>TEST4</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use before instead of append:

```js
$("ul li:nth-child(2)").before($("<li>").text("ADDDED TEST 5"));
$("ul li:nth-child(3)").before($("<li>").text("ADDDED TEST 6"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="a_rgt">
  <ul>
    <li>TEST1</li>
    <li>TEST2</li>
    <li>TEST3</li>
    <li>TEST4</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case if somebody still interested how to do it properly (and quicker) without dependency:

```js
const el = document.querySelector('ul li:nth-child(1)')
el.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<li>ADDDED TEST 6</li>');
el.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<li>ADDDED TEST 5</li>');
```

```html
 

<div class="a_rgt">
  <ul>
    <li>TEST1</li>
    <li>TEST2</li>
    <li>TEST3</li>
    <li>TEST4</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```